# Dynamically clearing an absolute positioned div based on browser size with jquery .css() property

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am working on a site, and have the code below.  What I'm trying to do is show a full screen absolute positioned video that takes the size of whatever the browser currently is, then show content under it. Since it's an absolute position div and I can't clear the div, I need to get the height of that div, then set the "margin-top" property to the height of the div for the content below the video.

```
#bgvid {
        border: solid 4px blue;
        position: absolute; 
        right: 0; bottom: 0;
        min-width: 100%; min-height: 100%;
        overflow-y: hidden;
        width: auto; height: auto; z-index: -1;
    }
    .wrap{
        height: 500px;
        border: solid 4px black;
    }
....
....
<div id="bgvid">
<video autoplay loop>
     <source src="https://ia600400.us.archive.org/8/items/TripDownMarketStreetrBeforeTheFire/TripDownMktStreet_clean_512kb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
</div><!--end of #bgvid-->
<div class="wrap">
    <h1>lorem ipsum</h1>
</div><!-- end of .wrap-->
....
....
<script type="text/javascript">
    var bgvidheight= $('#bgvid').height();
    var styles = {'margin-top':bgvidheight};
    $('.wrap').css(styles);
</script>
```

So this shows the .wrap div under the #bgvid div when the page loads, but when I resize the browser the position of the .wrap div stays where it was placed on loadand I need to reload in order to put it in the correct position under the video, obviously because the script will run everytime the page loads.

This is fine when someone opens the page on a phone or tablet, but if someone resizes their browser it will look screwy until they reload.

So my question is if there is a way to constantly get that height of the #bgvid div to feed into jquery?

Comment: You should probably `float:left` on the Elements and just switch between `clear:none` `and clear:left` in jQuery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
$(window).resize(function(){ 
    var height = $('#bgvid').height();
    //do stuff with the height
 });
```

Comment: That was it! Adding that under the current jquery code worked like a charm! Thanks!